# file_put_content function change the size of my picture

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload pictures to a server using file_put_content function but it seems that the file size is not the same. Any idea about how to conserve the same file size ? 
Here is my code :

```
    list($type, $img) = explode(';', $img);
    list(, $img)      = explode(',', $img);
    $image = str_replace(' ','+',$img);
    $data = base64_decode($image,true);
    $filename = $dir.$hash_user_id.$typeImage.'.'.$extension;
    file_put_contents($filename, $data);
```

Comment: what do you do with `$extension`?, if that replaces the extention of a jpg to png for example, that would probably change the size already

Comment: It's the extension of my picture ex : jpg, png, ..

Comment: Are you comparing the file size between the computer you uploaded from and the file on the server after uploaded? Is it two different operating systems? Some OS show the same size using different metrics. How far off are the file sizes?

Comment: In fact I use FileZilla to get my pictures uploaded so I added manually the picture then I upload my picture using php script and make comparaison between my pictures.

Comment: For the first question I'm trying to get the extension of picture to make sure I'm not loosing the extension

Comment: What contains $img? Why do you overwrite $img (twice!)? Why do you use str_replace and base64_decode (on what data anyway)? What are the results of your debugging attempts?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz $img contains the image encoded (starts with data:image/jpeg;base64,...)

Comment: And what do you mean by different size? which sizes do you compare?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz I compare current image on my desktop and the uploaded one.